# Is there a formal term for the "WWHW" and "WHWW" ordering of intervals in a perfect 5th?

Tags: theory, scales, intervals

The reason for my question is that I'm developing a simpler way, using one's fingers instead of the music staff to introduce basic theory to non-musicians.

It's called "THE Music Theory" - "THE" stands for "Two Handed Easier".

In THE course I define major & minor as the respective interval groupings of "WWHW" and "WHWW" as they are the only two patterns that concatenate to form diatonic scales - a P5 specifying the 'second tonic' of 'so', the first being 'do'.

Using this method one can quickly determine and see the interplay of scales, notes and chords - and even more quickly if you play guitar.

For example, If you ask me ‘What keys have a C-minor chord’ well it has to be B-flat, E-flat and A-flat, and!,  I can tell you that in those keys the C-minor chord is the 2nd, 6th and 3rd chords respectively - and that chord progression knowledge is the cornerstone for writing songs, solos, whatever … it’s core-harmony.

The shortcoming of the tetrachord method - sandwiching a "W" - gives you the seven notes of a scale but it doesn't create the helix pattern of the circle of fifths.

So I'm wondering if there already is a formal term for these two specific interval patters onto themselves ... not just as a portion of a mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the greek modes, and how do they differ from modern modes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11274/what-are-the-greek-modes-and-how-do-they-differ-from-modern-modes)

Comment: Please check the suggested duplicate to see whether it answers your question. You are asking about fifths, but instead the historical procedure was to consider tetrachords.

Comment: Thank you but my Q isn't directly about modes or a tetrachord ("WWH", sometimes introduced as two tetrachords sandwiched by a "W" equals a major key).

The reason for my question is that I'm developing a simpler way, using one's fingers instead of the music staff to introduce basic theory to non-musicians It's called "THE Music Theory" - "THE" stands for "Two Handed Easier".

In the course I define major & minor as the respective interval groupings of "WWHW" and "WHWW" as they combine to form diatonic scales.

So I'm wondering if there already is a formal term for these two combinations.

Comment: I realize the link isn't a direct answer, but I think it's as close as you'll get. I was pointing out that traditional theory builds up from tetrachords (e.g. C D E F) rather than five as expressed in your question (e.g. C D E F G), so for example a major scale is composed of two halves of WWH and WWH. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Yes,common and traditional but it doesn't build out the the double-helices of 5ths (and accidentals).

Many times I've seen 'diatonic = 7 notes'. But that's actually heptonic while dia-topic is 2-tonics, 'do' and 'so' - so two 'WWHW's result in Ionian.

And can't major scales can be non-diatonic? , e.g., harmonic major scale - it's major because it's built on WWHW.

So if there is no formal term for these two five-note patterns may I suggest:

WWHW = "Major Tonic Pattern" or "Core Major Pattern" (abbr. MCore) and WHWW = "Minor Tonic Pattern" or "Core Minor Pattern" (abbr. mCore)

Comment: What are you asking?  A perfect fifth is a 2:3 ratio.  What interval stack creates it is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, I agree Carl re:P5. I've tried to describe what I'm asking in the comment above ... if there are existing musical terms denoting the specific patterns of "WWHW" and "WHWW" as these are the only two orderings which result in diatonic scales, being Major and Minor, when concatenated. I believe this is offers a more useful approach for non-musicians to understand the origin of basic music theory.

In addition perhaps this is good place to ask if it would be appropriate to post a Music Theory question of the form "Would you like to test-drive my new approach to teaching music theory?"

Comment: @RandyZeitman this site is not a place for surveys, polls, and the like which a question like "Would you like to test-drive my new approach to teaching music theory?". You can bonce ideas off of our chat if you'd like, but it doesn't fit the main site.

Comment: diatonic
ˌdʌɪəˈtɒnɪk/
adjectiveMusic
adjective: diatonic

    (of a scale, interval, etc.) involving only notes proper to the prevailing key without chromatic alteration.
        (of a melody or harmony) constructed from a diatonic scale.

In this respect, harmonic major, mixolydian major, harmonic, natural and melodic minor are all diatonic.

Comment: Why not call it "pentachord"? Seems appropriate.

Comment: Super! Thank you Agnes! It's not just appropriate, it's correct!

Answer (score 2):

The comment above suggesting to call them pentachords seems to be correct to me. Specifically, the major (or Ionian) and minor (or Aeolian) pentachords. There's a wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentachord) but it's pretty bare -- I think tetrachord is by far the more common term, for historical reasons.

Pianists also have major and minor "five finger patterns," but I am pretty sure that terminology is specific to keyboard players.

Comment: Wow... didn't know that. Thank you!  

But why do you call WHWW Aeolian instead of Dorian?  I see that starting on the 6th would give WWHW but it's notes #6-10 vs. #2-6.

Comment: I chose Aeolian because I suspect it is more familiar to most people (because it's analogous to natural minor). You're correct that the Dorian pentachord would be the same. The difference between Dorian and Aeolian is scale degree 6, and these pentachords are only the first 5 notes.