# History of Tetrachords

Tags: theory, chords, scales, history, tetrachords

I posted a similar question not too long ago and it was suggested that I look into tetrachords and I quickly understood why, but now I have questions about tetrachords.

For what reason are diatonic tetrachords in a whole step-whole step-half step pattern, and why are they considered major and minor tetrachords if they would be (C-D-E-F and C-D-Eb-F) in comparison to a major and minor trichord (C-E-G and C-Eb-G).

I haven't even tried to interpret the chromatic and enharmonic tetrachords yet but I am sure it'll be easier to understand their purpose after first understanding the diatonic.

How did the originators of tetrachords decide to start tuning these ways?

Comment: Also: [What scale were the very first modes based on?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/96205/70803).

Comment: I believe the above and the "duplicate" post will answer your question, but, if you read them and don't feel the issue is sufficiently addressed, please edit your question to specify the detail(s) still at issue. I'll certainly vote to reopen should that prove the case.

Comment: @Aaron hey! I’ve read through them and I’m not quite sure how to apply them to my question. I’m more so trying to see if anyone can elaborate on why the Tetrachords are made of whole steps and half steps, and why the first and fourth strings are a fourth apart. Do you have any suggestions for how I should edit my question? The thing is I don’t necessarily have a specific question, but I guess this would be the biggest piece of my search. But I was also interested in why the spaces in the Tetrachord are different from Trichords but still called Major & Minor, it is part of the question I think.

Comment: Let me see if I follow. Your questions are: 1) Why did the ancient Greeks use tetrachords in the first place? 2) How did those tetrachords become whole and half steps? 3) How did those tetrachords evolve into scales? 4) How did scales become major and minor? 5) Why are chords separate from scales but named the same way?

Comment: @Aaron yup that’s close enough

Comment: Those are all really separate questions, some of which are answered elsewhere (e.g., #3 is answered in 'What scale were the very first modes based on?', linked above). My suggestion: edit your question to more specifically focus on "Why did the ancient Greeks choose tetrachord as the basis for their musical theory rather than some other structure?", then open the others as separate questions (so it isn't closed again for asking multiple questions or needing more focus).

Comment: @Aaron ok gotcha thanks! I will do that